# Should I use a Redis hash or a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, hash, redis

I have Rails app in which I have to maintain a hash that will be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

Most of the accesses will be reads and there will be few writes. I am trying to decide between using a Ruby hash and Redis hash.

The Redis hash is thread-safe and can store the data to disk. But, the persistence is not all that necessary.

Moreover, the writes to the hash are infrequent and the data to be written is basically the time itself at which it is being written. So, even if it is not thread-safe, the loss of precision due to a race condition is acceptable, since the time between concurrent writes could vary by only a few seconds at max.

My only concern with using a singleton Ruby hash is that updates are not thread-safe and not atomic. So, will a simultaneous non-atomic key update cause an Exception?

If not, will it make sense to maintain the singleton Ruby hash with no locks?

My concerns with using a Redis hash are that the size of the in-memory hash could be greater than the Ruby hash and the overhead of calling the redis-server. The concurrency and persistence are good to have but not necessary.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Once you run your application on production you might want to run multiple workers or even run the application on multiple servers. That said: Redis might be the better idea.

Comment: I am running the app on Puma, which can use multiple workers. So, does it mean that if I use a singleton hash when multiple workers are involved, different workers will have different app instances and so, a different hash for each instance? If it is so, will Redis be the only option to make a globally available hash?

Comment: That is correct: Puma workers run in a different processes and do not share memory. But you can also configure puma to run in multiple threads which share memory. So the answer is: It depends on your configuration. Redis would work in all configurations - even with multiple servers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is a correction based on Holger Just's comment correcting me.)

There is a library designed especially for your need called `concurrent-ruby`.

Check it out at https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby.

It has a Hash class (http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/Hash.html) and also a Map class (http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/Map.html) which they say is faster but does not conform completely to the Ruby Hash's semantics (e.g. does not guarantee ordering in order of key insertion).

Note that after installing the gem, the `require` required to use it is different from the gem name; you `require concurrent`:

```
require 'concurrent'
h = Concurrent::Hash.new
```

I haven't used it though, so I can't provide any personal feedback about it.

Comment: The [thread_safe](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/thread_safe) gem was merged into the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem which contains many additional primitives. The thread_safe gem is thus deprecated and is considered to be in maintenance mode only. For new developments, you should thus probably use concurrent-ruby instead. Since ActiveSupport 5 depends on concurrent-ruby, it should also be rather safe to use.